# Video encoding services

Tags: web-services, video-encoding

I need to be able to allow users to upload a wide variety of video files in various formats then clean them up and make them kosher for delivery to a dedicated content handler.

I've tried ffmpeg onsite but it has some serious flaws in regards to h.264.

Then I tried flixcloud.com which has a very good interface, api, and was looking like the perfect solution except it doesn't provide the video frame rate correctly.

Moving on I tried Ankoder.com and it does work, but unfortunately it's API is somewhat of a mess and has some quirks that are proving to be difficult to code around.

What other services are out there, will only accept answer from someone who has used a video transcoding service.

Update:
   Just started looking at http://www.encoding.com/ - seems interesting.

Comment: http://www.encoding.com/service/

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a number of transcoding services in the past and have found flaws with just about all of them. For the last 3 projects I have been involved with that involved media encoding I have used Expression Encoder, with great results. The application its self is a pleasure to use and simple to achieve the results needed, and the SDK is one of the best out there. Microsoft have definatly done a great job.